# How to monitor AWS infrastructure&workloads using Elasticsearch integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, filebeat, kibana-4

It is needed to intagrate AWS with Elasticsearch, I have found a couple of articles which describe general process:

1. Create and configure an S3 bucket
2. Create and configure an SQS queue.
3. Install and configure Filebeat and Metricbeat to collect Logs and
4. Metrics Collect logs from S3
5. Collect metrics from Amazon CloudWatch

f/e https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/observability/current/monitor-aws.html#monitor-aws

The question is where Filebeat and Metricbeat suppose to be installed f.e if I have complex infra with serverless items?

I also tried to connect with aws access and secret key in elasticsearch policies, bu no luck(data is not picked up)

Comment: You should check the newly released Elasticsearch Serverless Forwarder: https://www.elastic.co/blog/elastic-and-aws-serverless-application-repository-speed-time-to-actionable-insights-with-frictionless-log-ingestion-from-amazon-s3

Comment: Thanks, https://www.elastic.co/blog/elastic-and-aws-serverless-application-repository-speed-time-to-actionable-insights-with-frictionless-log-ingestion-from-amazon-s3 works for me, but may be you have similar doc for cloudwatch, I didn't find any exept the smal general part in doc above